# Android Multiple configurations for different customers

Tags: android, android-studio

devs

Please help me with some suggestions on working with multiple configurations for my Android project.

I have to customize the project for several customers (different customers will have different icons, text, even logic)
As I have to upload the apks to Google Play, I'm assuming they have to have different package names.
What's the best way to have different packages, yet making it relatively easy to maintain?

I know Android Studio helps with multiple configurations (we're still with Eclipse)
Also, I was thinking of a core library project and then having custom (client) projects.

Thanks a lot for all the help
Cristian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a customization like that it is best to make a build script which will download the latest code for a specific publisher from github/svn or something like that. It should also download publisher specific strings, launcher icons, name of the app and the end package package name, version, certificate to sign the application with, assets, rename all occurrences of default package... Make sure you exclude any unnecessary libraries that some publishers don't need and comment out the stuff related to that library. You can define start/end tags in code and then search for the start tag, replace it with /* and then replace the end tag with */ effectively commenting everything between them out. At the end the script runs gradle wrapper. First run clean and then build. It's also good to define the end output location of apk so it's easier to find.

The most easy way to build a build script like that is using bash scripts. They run on linux/mac or even both if you do it the right way. The whole think should run on a build server like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)

You will also need to provide some sort of interface for you customers to choose the options they want in their app, like for example checkboxes for push

- Parse
- UrbanAirship
- GCM
- ...

The most easy way it to make a simple webpage or use Jenkins directly

After the build is done, it is good to upload the final *.apk to a server where publishers can download the latest apk and then upload it to Google Play Store.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply, Bojan. We're gonna go with Jenkins as you suggested. It's been very helpful

Comment: Yes, Jenkins is quite ok, but our users did not fully understand how to properly use it and made a mess :/ so we made a simple idiot proof webpage to simply things for them and that website conveys the messages to the Jenkins.